# How do I create a file that is n size based on input?

Tags: ruby

I would like to create a dummy file with ruby code that takes up a certain amount of space based on the user input. I can't think of a way to do this. I know about fallocate and etcetera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Ruby's `File` class to create a file with a specific size based on user input. Here's some sample code that demonstrates this:

```
# Get the desired file size from the user
puts "Enter the desired file size in bytes:"
size = gets.chomp.to_i

# Create a new file with the desired size
File.open("dummy_file.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.truncate(size)
end
```

In this code, we first prompt the user to enter the desired file size in bytes. We then use `File.open` to create a new file named "dummy_file.txt" in write mode (`"w"`). The `File#truncate` method is called on the file object with the `size` argument to set the file size to the desired value.

Once this code is executed, you should see a new file named `"dummy_file.txt"` in your current directory with the specified size.

If your platform does not support the `truncate` method as @pjs points out below, you can accomplish this by repeatedly writing a block of data to the file until it reaches the desired size.

```
# Get the desired file size from the user
puts "Enter the desired file size in bytes:"
size = gets.chomp.to_i

# Open a new file for writing
File.open("dummy_file.txt", "w") do |file|
  # Define the block of data to write
  block_size = 1024 # You can adjust this to control the size of each block
  block = "x" * block_size

  # Write blocks of data to the file until it reaches the desired size
  while file.size < size
    remaining_bytes = size - file.size
    bytes_to_write = [block_size, remaining_bytes].min
    file.write(block[0, bytes_to_write])
  end
end
```

Comment: The [ruby docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/File.html#method-c-truncate) say "Not available on all platforms", so this is not a general or portable solution.

Comment: I've added an alternate way to accomplish this without using truncate in the answer above